# Difference between NotesDocument objects from database and in-memory?

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I have noticed in one of my Java agents that when storing a lot of Document objects in a Hashmap I get OutofMemoryException.
What I'm trying to achieve is this:

I want to populate my Domino database with information from an Oracle database. The logic is to get all from Oracle and then get all documents from Domino database. All new from Oracle is to be saved and all not in Oracle but in database shall be removed from Domino. A sort of replication of you will…

I start with looping all documents in the Domino database and store them in a HashMap with UNID as key and Document object as value:

```
dominoHash.put(doc.getUniversalId(), doc);
```

Then I loop the resultset and creates in-memory Document objects:

```
Document doc = db.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("MyField", rset.getString("MYCOLUMN");
oracleHash.put(rset.getString("UNID"), doc);
```

In my TEST environment I have +20000 Domino documents and the same in Oracle. In this case they are identical.
The OutOfMemoryException occurs always when trying to store in oracleHash even if I have excluded all Domino document logic from the code to "save memory"…

I thought the objects I'm storing in the different Hashmaps are the same but some how they are not. I can successfully store my Domino Document objects in a Hashmap but not my Oracle document objects.

To make it more strange the document stored from Domino has more fields than the Oracle view has columns.

Why could be the cause of this?

In this specific case I use org.openntf.domino API and haven't tried native API (yet).

Comment: Can I confirm, is it a Java OutOfMemoryException or causing a panic because of LookupHandles? Apparently the limit of Domino handles for R9 is 150,000, so it shouldn't hit that. But because you're putting the documents into a Map, they can't be recycled by the API, because they're still in use. You can use lotus.domino.Document and lotus.domino.Database to explicitly use non-ODA objects.

Comment: Yes it is a memory exception. 
But the funny thing is I get it when creating in-memory objects from oracle but not from domino.

Comment: Post stack trace of the exception.

Comment: If this is a pure java Agent then its not XPages and you should remove the XPages tag.  If it's an "XAgent" then obviously you should keep the tag.  I'm not exactly sure which it is so you should make that clear.  Thanks

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers I begin to lean towards your answer where all Domino objects not being recycled. I managed to loop and add to Maps all resources this morning without any MemoryExceptions and I think if I run the agent more than once today, memory will be full… the only solution is to loop all SQL objects and all Domino objects but that will create enormous I/O…

Comment: This has boiled down to a memory issue on the server. The total amount of Heap available is only 64MB. A request to server admins has been made to increase to a fourth of total memory on server. We have rewritten the agent three times now and we are not storing any Domino related objects anymore and still we face the OutOfMemoryException…
To be continued…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hardly a good idea to keep all Domino documents in memory. At some point in time you run out of the C handles in the core API.

You might want/need to change your approach. Trying to keep everything in memory will always  run out of memory once you reach "the size". What you need is, aptly named by @Andre Guirard, "The Pirate algorithm":

Have a view in Domino and Oracle each, that are **sorted** by your comparison key (The UNID as I understand it from your code). Lets presume N is Notes and O is Oracle. Your code (here pseudo code) would roughly look like this:

```
         OEntry = O.getFirst
         for all NEntry in N
             if NEntry.key > OEntry.key
                InsertFromOracle until NEntry.key = OEntry.key
             else if Nentry.key < OEntry.key
                DeleteFromNotes until NEntry.key = OEntry.key
             else
                SyncValuesFromOracleToNotes
             end if
          end for
         if O.hasMoreEntries
             InsertFromOracle until not O.hasMoreEntries
         end if
```

The InsertFromOracle of course need to check if there are elements left in Oracle to do that.

A [LotusScript example](http://www.openntf.org/catalogs/a2cat.nsf/$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?&action=openDocument&documentId=D01B7CAC6A34CD0B85257728006172E8) had been written by Andre (Look for the Pirates Agent, named after the swagger walking of a pirate)

You don't need to keep entire tables or document collections in memory. Since loading and comparing run in a single loop it should also perform quite well.

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: My intentions was to create maps and utilise Collections methods for removing and retaining. It seems like the JDBC connections create a more memory impact than I expected. I'll try the "pirate" approach. Thx

Comment: You actually might want to explore DECS or LEI. Could be smarter than trying to code yourself. I wrote about it here: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7G5CW5

Comment: I have changed it not to store any Documents in memory but still facing OutOfMemoryExceptions:
`11-11-2014 14:44:34   AMgr: Agent ('Copy Of Import Bonds|aImportBonds2' in 'R7\tradesec.nsf') error message: 11-11-2014 14:44:34 se.tradechannel.agents.ImportBondsImpl NotesMain
INFO: Starting Copy Of Import Bonds
11-11-2014 14:45:25   AMgr: Agent ('Copy Of Import Bonds|aImportBonds2' in 'R7\tradesec.nsf') error message: JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2014/11/11 14:45:25 - please wait.`

Comment: With 64MB heap you will not go anywhere. You can't use the HashMap for either of your datasets. Use the Pirate approach and ditch your Maps

Comment: I have now fixed this using a Map for my Domino docs storing only UNID and when looping SQL rset I look in Map if contians then remove it from Map and ignore from rset. The result is what I wanted; the Delta of both sides… If Domino Map is empty just loop and store docs…

Comment: Good to hear. So you don't need sync of content. Feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is an XAgent and you're getting OutOfMemoryExceptions when multiple sessions are hitting or multiple requests are being run, chances are it's to do with persistence. A number of sessions/instances of the page may be getting held in memory, causing it to add to the memory of the previous call to the page each time, which is what is causing the eventual OutOfMemoryException.

If it's the only content on an XPage that's running the process, set the viewState property to "nostate". If that's all the database is doing, you can set that in Xsp Properties.

Alternatively, if you need to serialize and retrieve the data within XPages itself, setting "Server page persistence" on Persistence tab of Xsp Properties to "Keep pages on disk" should solve the problem. Nothing will then get stored in memory. Once the page is loaded, the data for it will be stored on disk instead.

Comment: It's a POJA, Plain Old Java agent